# multiple colorbar in ocatve

Tags: matlab, octave, colorbar

I want to visualize the change of a vector in time using colorbar plots with octave. Let's say i have a vector U with some initial state and this vector evolves somehow. Then i would like to get something like

```
colorbar plot of the init state
colorbar plot after 1 time step
colotbar plot after 2 time steps
...
colotbar plot after n time steps
```

and so on in one window, 'n' is known. I can create one colorbar plot with

```
imagesc(U);
colorbar();
```

but i do not know how to stack them.

Edit: I do not have a real example but i imagine something like separated plot above each other.Maybe similar to a 2D colormap where the x-direction shows the colorplot of my vector and the y-direction represents the time. (maybe it's easier to store the data directly as an array but i would still be interested how to solve the problem)

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you want to *stack* them? Do you have an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have stated in your edit with x representing your vector U and y time you need an 2D array, for example PlotArray, with size n*length(U)

> PlotArray = zeros(n, length(U));

As far as visualizing it depends on if you want to update the plot as the simulation evolves or just plot the resulting plot with all timestamps.
Since number of timestamps are know it is easy to update the PlotArray during simulation for each timestep,

> PlotArray(timestep,:) = U;  % where U is a row array
>   colorbar(PlotArray);